# Adding a $ sign to online calculator output field

Tags: javascript, html

This is just the code that writes to the answer boxes. Just need a simple method and exact placement of code. Like "$" or '$' but exactly where to place it in string.

```
 var dues1 = (annual_dues * 3).toFixed(0);

 var fv3=(pv*(v3-1)/n6).toFixed(0);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do and provide all the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what you are expecting.

Assuming like below

```
 var dues1 = "$ " +  (annual_dues * 3).toFixed(0);

 var fv3= "$ " + (pv*(v3-1)/n6).toFixed(0);
```

in currency format....

```
  var number = 3500;

  console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
 // → '3,500' if in US English locale
```

in your case, it can be (not tried live example...)

```
 var dues1x = (annual_dues * 3).toFixed(0);

 var dues1 = "$ " +  console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(dues1x);

 var fv3x = (pv*(v3-1)/n6).toFixed(0);

 var fv3 = "$ " + console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format( (fv3x);
```

Comment: Expecting this: $900 as the answer. Thank you, your advice worked. I just did not know or think to put the $ equation in front of my existing formula. Much appreciated.

Comment: How would I display the number with a comma $9,000 vs $9000

Comment: Trying it now but seems to not work -stops entire calc from performing, double checking entries

Comment: no..m no need to add var number.. it is just example

Comment: try new edited code below " In your case..." line